как связать контейнеры докеры?
у меня есть 3 контейнера,в них запускаются бд ,апп и pgadmin,как мне связать эти контейнера? 
вот мой url для подключения к бд :
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?schema=public" 
вот мой docker compose file


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Укажи в качестве хоста(ip) для подключения имя сервиса (в твоем случае db), докер автоматически резолвит имена контейнеров в адреса для обращения в пределах одной сети, для внешнего подключения нужен айпи адрес машины.

Я указывал db все равно не работает

В апп строку подключения передаешь через env.
В пгадмин после входа можно указать базу к которой подключаешься

DATABASE_URL это переменная окружения но все равно не работает

Не вижу её в композ файле

А нужно еще добавить POSTGRES_URL=URL?
